# Irreducibility of Projective Cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

I have always (perhaps wrongly) assumed that the infinite cone in projective 2-space is irreducible. I'm just looking for confirmation that the $\mathbb{P}^2$ curve defined by:

$X^2+Y^2-Z^2 \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$

is irreducible? It is because I am trying to find its intersection with a homogenized ellipse

$X^2-2XZ+16Y^2-3Z^2 \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$

and I yield another line/infinite set of solutions, making me think that they have a common irreducible component.

Thanks in advance and apologies!

Comment: The first curve is indeed irreducible. You should get three points (one of multiplicity two) when you calculate this intersection. If you're interested in where exactly your error is, perhaps you could post your work?

Comment: hi there! thank you for your speedy response! when plotting the real locus of these varieties for the affine chart $\{Z=1\}$ in Sage I get the 3 intersection points exactly as you describe - I now realize I made an oversight in my calculation which I could not spot the for life of me! I'm very sorry for wasting your time on such a trivial matter!